# ¿Error con la version de jdk xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin, android

Obtengo un error al usar Xamarin:

> xamarin java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: Descárgate la última versión de JDK y selecciónala.

Answer (score 1):

La versión 52.0 se refiere a la versión específica del JDK

1.- Xamarin Android para la version que estas usando requiere [JDK-8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) en su versión 1.8.

2.- Otra de las soluciones que a mi me funciono, es bajarla el nivel de compilacion a tu aplicación, click derecho en tu solución android y vas a propiedades, ahi veras las versiones de compilacion yo las baje a 6.0 marshmallow, ya que por default creo que te esta compilando con Nougat, una ves que hagas eso, click derecho en tu solucion, clean y despues build, ya con eso debería compilar sin problemas de version.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que [actualizar tu JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) a 1.7.0+,

**El requerimiento es JDK 7 (1.7) 32-bits.**

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/